# c++ constructor and derived object

Tags: c++, class, constructor

I got this code and wonder why in Class Cylinder the line

```
Cylinder(double r, double h) : base (r), height(h) {}
```

is not

```
Cylinder(double r, double h) : base.radius (r), height(h) {}
```

I mean a double is being handed over and base is a Cylinder,shouldnt it be base.radius ?

```
// member initialization
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Circle {
    double radius;
  public:
    Circle(double r) : radius(r) { }
    double area() {return radius*radius*3.14159265;}
};

class Cylinder {
    Circle base;
    double height;
  public:
    Cylinder(double r, double h) : base (r), height(h) {}
    double volume() {return base.area() * height;}
};

int main () {
  Cylinder foo (10,20);

  cout << "foo's volume: " << foo.volume() << '\n';
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: There's no inheritance or derived objects?

Comment: Actually no, because you need to call the (only) constructor of the base class!

Comment: Are you confused by the naming `base` somehow?

Comment: Are you thinking about the `base` keyword from C#? It doesn't exist in C++.

Comment: Why did you roll back my edit? As mentioned there's no deriving involved! Have another downvote for making your question unclear again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all there is no inheritance in your code. Second, when you call the `Cylinder` constructor, its members get constructed. As `Circle` has no default constructor you have to make sure that during construction of a `Cylinder` the constructor of the `Circle` is called. If you had

```
Cylinder(double r, double h) : height(h) {}
```

the compiler would complain about the missing default constructor of `Circle` because if you dont call the constructor explicitly the `Circle` would be constructed using

```
Circle::Circle()
```

which does not exist (deleted because `Circle` declares a different constructor). Also

```
Cylinder(double r, double h) : base.radius (r), height(h) {}
```

cannot work <s>because radius is private in `Circle`</s> because you may only initialize members of `Cylinder` in the initializer list (even members of a base class are not allowed).

Comment: Thx  this sentence " Second, when you call the Cylinder constructor, its members get constructed."  made it all clear to me :=)

Answer (score 3):

> I got this code and wonder why in Class Cylinder the line
>
> ```
> Cylinder(double r, double h) : base (r), height(h) {}
> ```
>
> is not
>
> ```
> Cylinder(double r, double h) : base.radius (r), height(h) {}
> ```

Calling `base.radius (r)` won't work, since it's a `private` member of `Circle`.
Even if it wouldn't be `private` you can't access it during construction in the initializer list.
It's perfectly fine to use the `Circle` constructor to initialize `radius` though.

Comment: Being `private` is not the only reason. Make `radius` `protected` or even `public` and you'll see.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition Yes you are right. I mentioned that additionally (don't have a better wording).

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the name `base` here is very, very bad; your `Circle` object is not a base!!

And, no, a class cannot directly initialize members of its members (or members of a real base). That would be a conflict of interest, a confusion of responsibility, a conflagration of sensibility.

A class provides an *interface* to managing it, and that interface consists of functions, not direct access to members. How confusing would it be if you'd gone in and altered the `Circle`'s data without even letting it know!

You initialize an object with its constructor, and let that constructor do what it thinks is right. In this case, the constructor will indeed set the `radius` member, as you intend.

Read about [black boxes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_box).

Comment: A cylinder has bases on top and bottom, hence the naming. From the geometrical POV the naming is fine.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: I get that but it's still a terrible choice in a C++ program.